# Grabar 2 tablas con JPA pero el vinculo no es Padre - > Hijo

Tags: java, jpa

Trato de describir el problema de la manera mas sencilla.
tengo 2 tablas una que guarda las facturas de los proveedores y que se dan de alta y en otra tabla tengo cheques recibidos.
El proceso es el siguiente, algunas de esas facturas que se dan de alta por primera vez,
se pagan con cheques, que ya existen en la base de datos.
Necesito que se relacionen entre si.
Lo que hice fue plantear una relacion manytoone tal como se ve, en la entidad cheques:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cheque")
public class Cheque implements Serializable { 
...............
@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idtotalc", insertable = false, updatable =false)
private Total total;
```

Si antes de hacer el "insert" en la entidad "Total", donde se guardan las facturas,
guardo los cheques, me hace un insert de 2 registros en la tabla Total. Este es el codigo:

```
//graba cheques
for (Auxiliar p : chequesT) { 
            idCheque = p.id;
            impo = p.cancelado;
            if (impo != 0) {
                Cheque ChT = chequesTDao.buscaChequePorId(idCheque);
                ChT.setBaja(fecha);
                ChT.setDestino("Baja S/Cpbte. " + tipocomp.getAbreviatura() + " " + letra + " " + String.valueOf(puntovta) + "-" + String.valueOf(numero));
                ChT.setTotal(total);
                res =chequesTDao.updateCheque(ChT);
            }
        }

// guarda total y las tablas asociadas
res = totalDao.insertTotal(total);

if (!res.equals("")) {
        errorGE = true;
        json.addProperty("errorGE", "true");
        json.addProperty("mensaje1", res);
    }
```

Ahora, si invierto el proceso grabar, es decir, primero la tabla Total, y luego los cheques,se graba todo correctamente, pero entonces, si hubiese un error al grabar la table cheque, ¿como podria deshacer el insert en la tabla total y todas las tablas que tiene asociadas?

Como deberia plantear la relación en este caso?
agradezco desde ya sus ideas.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comento la manera en que lo resolvi, tal vez a alguien mas le resulte util.
Modifique el EJB de la siguiente manera, cree un nuevo metodo, de manera que en ese mismo metodo me grabara las 2 tablas, de manera que de producirse un error, automaticamente se aborta el proceso.

```
 public String insertTotalUpdateChequeT(Total total, List<ChequeElige> chequesT) {
    int idCheque = 00;
    float impo = 0.0f;

    try {
        em.persist(total);

        for (ChequeElige cht : chequesT) {
            idCheque = cht.getId();
            impo = cht.getCancelado();

            //Graba 
            if (impo != 0) {
                Cheque cheque = chequesTDao.buscaChequePorId(idCheque);
                cheque.setBaja(total.getFecha());
                cheque.setDestino("Baja S/Cpbte. ");
                cheque.setTotal(total);
                em.merge(cheque);
            }
        }
       .....................
```

No se si es la manera mas adecuada o elegante, pero funciona.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer se llama secuencia de transacción, generalmente solo se le llama transacción.

Para detalles de que es una transacción y la propiedad ACID puedes ver esta explicación.
[Detalle sobre las transacciones](https://diego.com.es/transacciones-en-sql)

En jpa para manejar las transacciones debes ocupar las siguientes anotaciones: `@Transactional` y `@EnableTransactionManagement`

`@Transactional` Se utiliza sobre los métodos de tus servicios

Por ejemplo

```
@Service
public class TransactionalProductService {  
    private final ProductRespository productRespository;

//si alguna query(save, update, read, etc) falla dentro de este método con 
//anotación transactional nada será cambiado en tu base de datos.
//esto se conoce como rollback (volver atrás)
    @Transactional
    public void updateOnCondition(Long id, String name) {
//aquí inicia tu secuencia de acciones a la base de datos si alguna falla 
// tu base de datos no habrá cambiado -- rollback
        Product product = findById(id).get();
        product.setName(name);

        if (product.getPrice().compareTo(new BigDecimal("10")) == 0) {
            productRespository.save(product);
        }
    }
```